# Combination of generic collections

Tags: c#, generics

I have several instances of

```
abstract class Repository<T> where T : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> Get<T>(){...};
}
```

with different instances of `ViewModelBase` in each one

How do I combine all of them into a class `GlobalRepository`
with a method that will return specified collection from containing instance of Repository?

```
class GlobalRepository
{
    //... List of Repository<ViewModelBase>

    public ObservableCollection<T> Get<T>()
    {
        return (Containing instance of Repository<T>).Get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? I haven't tried it now, but can you redefine the generic parameter `T` for the method if it has already been declared for the class?

Comment: I though you can't, but actually it's possible :) But I would never recommend that.

Comment: @ O. R. Mapper If I understood you correctly, the generic `T` in method is constrained within `T` in class

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<T>` constraint after Get method is not needed, since you have it in the abstract class definition. You do not need it on both places, so one of them can be skipped.

Moreover, if you make the `Repository<T>` static, you will not need any `GlobalRepository`.
Calling for proper data could then look like:

```
var data = Repository<T>.Get();
```

*Note: this works, if you let the generics in static class headers. Not sure, if it works the same when you bind  it with the Get method, but I'm sure there are workarounds.*

But if you still insist on a `GlobalRepository` class, then you probably should equip that class with a field like this `Dictionary<Type, Repository<ViewModelBase>>`, where `Type` will be the actual type you ask for. Your Global class method would not need to be generic then:

```
class GlobalRepository
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Repository<ViewModelBase>> _repoDict;

    public GlobalRepository()
    {
        _repoDict = new Dictionary<Type, Repository<ViewModelBase>>();
        //Guess here could be some Assembly lookup for all derived classes
        //But if you do not intend to expand them a lot, it can be hardcoded
        Repository<ViewModelBaseType> repo = new Repository<ViewModelBaseType>()
        _repoDict.Add(ViewModelBaseType, repo);            
            //the similar for all of the repositories
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Get(Type t)
    {
        if(!_repoDict.ContainsKey(typeof(t)){
            //throw your argument exception here
        }

        Repository<ViewModelBase> repo;
        _repoDict.TryGetValue(t, repo);

        ObservableCollection<t> collection = repo.Get();
        return collection;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** this certainly is **not** production ready code

*There could be some casting needed, but I think you could still try going static, unless you really need to create more instances of each Repository -> I am assuming from the class name here.*